# Can I make a window close in Google Chrome using javascript when launched from a desktop icon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've got a web application that I'm working on. What I want to happen is this: Form pops up on the computer at a certain time, User submits the form, the form processes, the page closes.

The part I have trouble with is the page closing part. I've tried running without it, and when I check the machine there will be 20 instances of the form open - the users just are not closing it on their own for whatever reason despite being told to do so.

I found that if I run Chrome in kiosk mode, then I can use a function like this to close the window:

```
function CloseWindow() {
    window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
}
```

...despite the fact that the window was not opened via javascript. The problem is though that the kiosk mode comes up full screen and this is frustrating to the users since it effectively locks them out from doing other things.

If I open Chrome in app mode or any other mode, this code doesn't work. So I guess I've got a 3 part question:

Can I run Chrome kiosk mode in anything other than full screen? If not, is there someway of getting similar code to function in app mode? If not that... any other ideas for getting it to work the way that I want?

Thanks!

Comment: My answer posted under another question seems solution for this case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25145907/3205524

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility close by JS only windows which created by JS. (This rule is rightly for all browser)

Another way to solve the problem is creating chrome extension http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

API methods like `windows.getAll` and `windows.remove` can be used for that. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html.