# How can I close a Chrome Kiosk page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to close a page from kiosk pages.
I tried to add a button and onclick, a self.close() function fires but it didn't work.
I tried as well hacky workaround proposed by Brock Adams in:
[window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)
But it only turn the screen white and do not close the page.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am also trying to resolve the same issue you are having.  I have not been able to find a solution.