# window.close() not working in chrome version 36.0.1985.143

Tags: javascript

The code i used in the javascript to close the window is as follows

```
window.open('','_self','');
window.close();
```

in jsp

```
<a href="javascript:jscloseWindow()">Close</a>
```

it's not working in chrome version 36.0.1985.143, it worked in previous chrome version, IE and in FF also. How can i fix it.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That has always been a hack to get around the fact you should not be able to close a window.

Comment: i can't believe that actually worked at some point, glad they fixed the bug.

Answer (score 0):

The [chrome latest release](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.in/2014/07/stable-channel-update.html) has changed that functionlity as there has been several security issues because of that. You need to try like this:

```
chrome.windows.remove(integer windowId, function callback)
```

You can check [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows)

Comment: This only works with Chrome extensions, which the OP does not seem to be using.

Comment: @ComFreek:- Do correct me if I missed something but I thought that OP wants to work it on Chrome as he mentioned:- `it's not working in chrome version 36.0.1985.143`

Comment: That's right, but that does not necessarily mean that the OP aims at developing a Chrome extension. Due to the mention of FF and IE, I *guess* that the OP is currently creating a normal website.

Comment: @ComFreek:- I do agree with that. But I thought that OP is facing the issue with Chrome only as it was there in the question title also. My bad! (So Should I delete my answer?)

Comment: No, I would at least wait for a comment by the OP. (I'm not a friend of deleting all irrelevant posts on SO, but your answer unfortunately won't help future visitors because `window.close()` - if used - always works in Chrome extensions.)

Comment: @ComFreek:- Yes I do agree with you but I think the Chrome extension may help others to identify it. Anyways i will wait for OP to respond. P.S. :- *May be I will get some downvotes for this :(*

Comment: i am not using any chrome extension, i am working for a company's website, previously it worked perfectly in all browsers. Recently i have update the chrome in my machine, after that the close hyper link is not working in only chrome browser. i need to fix this. i tried to implement chrome.windows.remove(integer windowId, function callback)...but didn't work..please help me. Thanks

Comment: I tried the kiosk mode also, the window.close() not working in chrome kiosk of the same version...

Comment: @user3780032 This is a [security feature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19768082/603003). You cannot close windows which weren't opened by scripts. The only solution would be to write a Chrome extension, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: Ok..thank you sir..i will inform my users to not to use chrome..instead they can go with IE and FF.