# how close webpage in google chrome using VB in code behind

Tags: asp.net

hi in my web site it had a close button on-clicking it i want to clean cache and close the site

```
  Public Sub CloseIM_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles button


        Try
            Session.Item("UserName") = Nothing
            Session.RemoveAll()

            Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now().Subtract(New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0))
            Response.Expires = 0
            Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> { self.close() }</script>")
'' i used above line to close but it is not working in google chrome working properly in IE all versions

End sub
```

i used  Response.Write(" { self.close() }") to close but it is not working in Google chrome 
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: thaknks for the reply @EdSF