# window.close() function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with window.close() function. I have a simple HTML script:

```
<body>
<a href="http://www.gmail.com" class="one">gmail</a><br />
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="one">google</a><br />

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

<script src="project.js"></script>
</body>
```

I want to open the above url's in different windows. Once the url's are loaded, the windows should close itself without any alerts. The below javascript code lets the url's open in different windows. But it closes only 'google.com' and the html webpage. The 'gmail' website remains open.

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.onclick = function() {
    var getLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("one");

    for(var i=0; i<=(getLinks.length-1); i++) {
        window.open(getLinks[i]);
        getLinks[i].onload = window.close();
    }
}
```

What am I missing in this code. Any help would be appreciated. 
Note: the links are only for test.

Comment: This part `getLinks[i].onload = window.close();`. That is not how you do it. Either remove the `()` or wrap it in an anonymous function.

Comment: You have added `onload` attribute to the `<a href..` elements which are already loaded. You code cannot close other windows from this window.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("http://google.com", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");    // Opens a new window
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();                                                  // Closes the new window
}
```

Easily found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zc2g7nkr/

It works fine in Chrome and i do not have to allow to block pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible any longer to close a window you have not created.

Take a look at this [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that certain browsers do not allow you to close a window using javascript.

There are bugs that prevent it - specifically that the browser won't let code from one website close a window that is opened to a different website.

```
var win = window.open("http://www.google.com", '1366002941508','width=500,height=200,left=375,top=330');

setTimeout(function () { win.close();}, 3000);
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N5rve/)**

It works fine in Firefox when you allowing popup,

It opens a popup in chrome but it do not allow you to close a window using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A page to B page

```
window.open('B.html', '_blank');
window.open('','_self').close();
```

page close

```
window.open('','_self').close();
```