# As an HTTPHandler.ashx finishes ProcessRequest how to close the browser window with code

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I have an HTTPHandler which performs a little unit of work. I have no "output" I want to display. Is there a method of closing the browser window from the code as I exit the sub:

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
'   unit of work
'   would like to close browser window here
End Sub
```

Details of the unit of work that are important to the end user are sent by email. Is there a simple way to close the browser window (or tab) with code (without Javascript if possible)?

UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
context.Response.Write("<script>window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();<script>")
```

With Google Chrome, I just get back the code as a message (not the "action" intended). Does more need to be wrapped into Response.Write or did I misunderstand something?

UPDATE No. 2:

I am still researching. Cannot get this to work; even with a Response.Redirect to the following closeWindow.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Google chrome debugger gives this error:

```
scripts may only close the windows that were opened by it
```

and nothing else happens. So I searched and found this SO thread:

[window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Apparently, there is more to this. If I can't get it to work in Chrome, then I will abandon and just spit out a simple response. Still researching here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the window via JavaScript would be the only way, so you'd have to write the following to Response:

```
string closeWindow = @"<html><head></head><body><script>window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();</script></body></html>";
context.Response.Write(closeWindow);
```

The first statement prevents a prompt on almost all browsers.

Comment: @JohnAdams, the script has to be in an html page in order to get executed. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. Apparently more to this issue. Please see my 2nd update. Thought you should know where I stand on this and I do appreciate your quick help.