# Close browser window in Angular SPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried quite a few versions of the window.close() method trying to get around the "Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script." error and have settled on the code below. I no longer receive the scripts error, but all the below does is redirect to my index page of my single page app.
Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas?

So I call it from this page (ng-click) **/index.html#/complete**

and it redirects me to **/index.html#/**

```
$window.open($window.location.pathname, '_self').$window.close();
```

Comment: Try `open(location, '_self').close();`

Comment: This was one of the solutions I attempted before. I got this error in the console, "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."

Comment: you aren't adding the hash to url created by `location.pathname`

Comment: I updated the code and still experienced the same redirect problem. $window.open($window.location.pathname+'#/', '_self').close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open(location, '_self').close();
```

is a workaround which you can use. The error you are getting on using that is:

```
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.
```

Which is correct, you will not be allowed to close windows you didn't create.

See the full explanation here: [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: Thanks. For all curious I ended up using the following which closed IE without prompt. It did not work in Chrome as mentioned by Chankey above. open(location+'#/', '_self').close();