# How to close web page using c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I create popoup window:

```
window.open(msg,'LoginPopup');
```

After popup window  implemnet a **Get request** to this function in the server:

```
public void GmailOAuthCallback(string code)
{
    object contacts = GmailServiceWorkflow.GetContacts(code);
}
```

I want to close the window.

Any idea how can I close the popup window whithin GmailOAuthCallback  function?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to close the window through JavaScript. C# has no control over the browser. But, as a security feature, it's difficult to close a window from code. Read more here: [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)