# ScriptManager after button submit

Tags: asp.net

I have written a script manager to open a page in new tab. The scriptManager is called on a button click, I want when the button click is called the popup window should get close. Please see my scriptmanager.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", String.Format("window.open('{0}','_tab ')", ResolveUrl("dummy.aspx")), true);
```

Please help to close the popup window

Comment: While this is technically possible to do if the new window is in the same domain as the parent window, there are a number of security and usability reasons why this is a bad idea.  If you need to open a window that the parent page has control of, consider using an ajax popup window instead.
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

Comment: can u help me with the code. The page is not opening

Comment: Sorry, old link.  Try this one:  https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ModalPopup%20Control&referringTitle=Tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done, In another way. As the senior management told to to it another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can save instance of `window.open` and  use that instance to close. Like declare global variable in aspx , say `var win;` in `script` tag, modify `ScriptManager` to use following.

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", String.Format("win = window.open('{0}','_tab ')", ResolveUrl("dummy.aspx")), true);`

And if you want to close the pop up , from the page who opened popup, then use following

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup","win.close();", true);`

And if you want to close with in popup page, then use following.

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup","window.close();", true);`

Having said all of these, there is **BIG disclaimer**. In short, close does not work most of times, because of browser security.  Following are the details.

Actually due to security reason and user experience aspects you can now can't cause the browser to be closed[Completely], only popup windows can be closed or the one parent to a script.

Just go through this - [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)
More link - http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html#dom-window-close

Comment: I want to close the popup after the button submit. I cant use both the ScriptManager at the same time

Comment: @NadeemKhan, these are alternatives, you have to use only one, let me know from where do you want to close?

Comment: I need to close after the button submit.

Comment: Is it from `from the page who opened popup` or `pop up it self has to be closed on button submit?`

Comment: popup itself has to be closed on button submit

Comment: Then use 2nd one i.e. `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup","window.close();", true);`

Comment: but it will not open my new tab

Comment: You told earlier that, you need to `close`, but you are asking that `will not open my new tab`? I am not getting clearly what you want

Comment: I want to close my tab after the button submit, which is in popup

Comment: If i get it correctly, you have already opened a popup, and in popup you are doing some operation, then in there , on button submit, you will close that pop up (button exists in popup), then you can use the script which i told you earlier.

Comment: yes now you get correctly, but for the closing popup. which script should I use. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63457/discussion-between-arindam-nayak-and-nadeem-khan).

Comment: Use this script ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup","window.close();", true);