# Self exit button

Tags: javascript, exit

I got my page to open with JS, with

```
<a href="javascript:openNewWindow();">
```

Now, the webpage will open in _self. I need to find a way to get a link, that will close my window. This doesnt work:

```
<a href="javascript:window.close();">
```

Now what to do? Anyone knows a better way to close self window? The second script **has** to be in the opened page.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close), `window.close()` should work fine. If it doesn't you have to provide more information. A complete example would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

**This is a correction of my previous answer:**

```
newwindow=window.open();
newdocument=newwindow.document;
newdocument.write("Hello World.<input type='button' value='close' onclick='window.close()' />");
newdocument.close();
```

as you can see, window.close() works ok.

**For a specific example,** you can use this -> create 2 files:
1. windowOpener.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="open" onclick="window.open('newWindow.html')" />
</body>
</html>
```

2. newWindow.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="close" onclick="window.close()" />
</body>
</html>
```

if you'll run windowOpener.html and click 'open' it will open 'newWindow.html'. clicking 'close' in the new opened window, will close it. voila.

Comment: "The second script has to be in the opened page."

Comment: Sorry, but its the same as what i did. It does not help me.

Comment: Didnt quite get your 2nd answer... I'm pretty new in js. Also, will it work when i insert it in the new page? What exactly to write and where?

Comment: I added specific example with 2 html files.

Comment: OK, now the new window opens in a new page. I need it to open in _self, replacing the previous page. Does that make it more complicated? Also, I'm going away, so i will not respond in the near 3 hours :(

Comment: I don't think it can be done.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome