# Closing a window after the page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to write a JavaScript function that will work on Firefox 5.0. I need the page to fully load, and then close. What I'm trying to do is:

```
var temp = window.open(link);

temp.window.onload = function () {
    temp.window.close();
}
```

But so far all it does is open the new tab, but doesn't close it.

Is there any way to successfully accomplish this?

Comment: Have you access to openning window code? I mean maybe it is better to put second part of your code to new window?

Comment: I'm a beginner at Javascript, can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Is the link in a different domain or sub domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe create new js file for that window and have just window.close(); inside.

Comment: This actually worked just fine! Thanks, I just had the server send a new js like you said and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

First if the link is not in the same domain, you will not be able to close the window because of the same origin policy.

Listens for the onload event with addEventListener

```
var temp = window.open(link); 
temp.addEventListener('load', function() { temp.close(); } , false);
```

if you need to support old IEs than you would need to attachEvent

```
var temp = window.open(link); 
temp[temp.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent']( (temp.attachEvent ? 'on' : '') + 'load', function() { temp.close(); }, false );
```

---

There is no need to open up a window to hit a web page.

You can:

- Make an Ajax request  - must be same domain
- Set a hidden iframe
- Set an image source

Answer (score 1):

If you have a access to the popup window you can add this:

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        open(location, '_self').close();
    });
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
     open(location, '_self').close();
   };
</script>
```

I also suggest you read this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19768082/1017298)

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like

```
function closed(){
    setTimeout("window.close()", 6000);
}
```

Comment: So you just guess the page is fully loaded after 6 seconds?