# How to close a html window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

First, I use hash tag to change page hash without a reload.

Second, I tried to close a window by clicking a button using jquery:

```
 $("#finish").click(function() {
    window.close();
});
```

Chrome tells me "you may not close the window not open by the script". However I am always on the same page, just the hashtag changes.

Any workarounds or ideas?

Comment: You can only close a window you've opened with `window.open`. You can't just close a users window on them.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome