# Keyboard Shortcut on asp.net Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to apply the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>  (closes a browser tab)  on an asp.net button. When I click on the asp.net button, it should work like the above controls. Is it possible? And if it is, from where can I get the code for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>(close a browser tab).

`window.close()` won't work to close a browser's tab.

Comment: How you come to know that it is nearly useless?

Comment: @Amit `window.close()` does not work on the current window if it is invoked from a script (it only works in the console, and on other windows you have opened) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

Comment: You have not specified your problem is with specific browser? Is it?  It might be bug or something wrong with the code. Do not assume. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/GjsCrvPYGlA

Comment: It is not working anymore, because Chrome has actually fixed a long standing bug.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: it won't work, because you cannot close the current page with JavaScript (well, you can do it from your own developer console, but not from a script). Please take a look at this question for details: [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)