# Alternative to window.close() method for Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I want to close my window/tab when the close button is clicked on the same page.

I used `window.close()` method. It works perfectly for IE versions, but it doesn't work for Firefox and Chrome.

I searched a lot for a solution. Please give me a demo solution.

Comment: Show us the code you are trying that you say doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close)

> [`Window.close()`] is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

So in order to use this method, you have to use the `window.open()` method to be able to close it via `window.close()`.