# Closing current browser window/tab using JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, browser

I’m developing a small web app, and I want to add a ‘close’ button.

The app runs inside Chrome window, and runs from a desktop shortcut (there's no opening window).
I’m using AngularJS on client side & NodeJS backend.

Every solution I've tried:

`$window.close();`

`$window.self.close();`

`$window.open(‘’, ‘_self’, ‘’); $window.close();`

Returns this error:

> "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."

Any other creative idea how to bypass/hack this restriction without setting the browser’s configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

Comment: You cannot do it. If you could, it would be treated as a security exploit and the attack would be fixed quickly.

Comment: @omar-ali none of the suggestions in that url works :/

Comment: @Pointy That;s why I'm asking that, if there's a knows hack that works for now.

Comment: Overwrite the whole DOM with a text called 'Please Close this Window'