# what is the jquery command or plugin to close the window which will work on all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

On click of bootstrap modal window, i need to close the entire window. I know window.close() is no more supported by Chrome. Is there any jquery command or any third party plugin to acheive this?

Existing solutions are not working to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: Unless your window was opened programatically, most modern browsers will not allow you to close it programatically. FF simply blocks it while IE and Chrome will pop-up the user asking if that is what they want.