# Make a Bootstrap Large button with href and winclose

Tags: php, button

I'm trying to make a large Bootstrap button with `href` and winclose onclick.

Here is my script:

```
<p style="word-wrap: break-word;"><button href="http://fenatoo.esy.es/down.php/" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to Proceed..." onClick="closeWin();">Continue</button><br/></p>
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the button to take you somewhere, it can be wrapped in an anchor tag like so:

```
<a href="http://example.com/">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Continue</button>
</a>
```

or it can simply be converted to an anchor tag:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Continue</a>
```

As far as closing the window, I assume that `closeWin()` is some custom JavaScript function of yours. If that isn't working the best I can tell you without the code for it is that it may not be working due to browser security measures as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19768082/1454953).