# Simulate CTRL+W onclick on element

Tags: javascript

Hei guys, i'm trying to simulate <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> on click on image. So i have:

```
<img id="target" src="something.png"/>
```

And i try to add a click event on this image which call a function that simulate <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> from keyboard.

I thought it should be something like this:

```
function closeWindow(){
            var theObject = document.getElementById("target");

            var pressEvent = document.createEvent ("KeyboardEvent");
            pressEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, window, true, false, false, false, 87, 0);
            theObject.dispatchEvent(pressEvent);
        }
```

The simulated <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> should have the same event as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> pressed by user from keyboard, i only need to close the tab by pressing a button/image.

AND NO, i cant use `window.close();` as this method doesnt work if the page wasnt created by script.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

Answer (score 4):

You can't send fake keystrokes to the browser chrome from a webpage.

Even if you could, it would make the restructions on `window.close` pretty pointless if you could bypass them by faking keystrokes.

You can't close a window/tab you didn't open. It doesn't belong to you.

Comment: If i use ctrl+w from keyboard its working, i dont see any reason why i cant fake by code ctrl+w

Comment: I think the browser doesnt know if i pressed em by user from keyboard or i simulated them from code, it just gets some code (87 + true - ctrlkey) and it should do the trick

Comment: @OzZie The browser is not that stupid. It knows what came from a hardware keyboard and what came from javascript.

Comment: So you're saying that aint any way of closing current tab on all major browsers?

Comment: @OzZie You can only close a window you've created. It's a strict security requirement from all major browsers.