# How can I close the current browser tab when the user click on a button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

In a page I have a 'Close' button that when clicked has to close the current browser tab (the tab in which is the page that contain this close button). So I wrote something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="color: #0F8BB0;" onclick="window.close();">
    Close
</button>
```

But it doesn't work and the current browser tab is not closed. Why? What am I missing? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: You can only close child windows (or tabs) that have been created from the original tab - you cannot close the originator.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it correctly, however browsers prevent you from closing a window if your javascript didn't create it.

So basically you can only close a window if you opend that window through javascript.

Also see: [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: and there is not any way to force this behavior and close it?

Comment: no sorry there is no way around this, because of security reasons/user experience.