# How to detect if an <input type="color"> color picker is opened and closed

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a color input like this:

```html
<input type="color" />
```

I need to detect when the native color picker is open and when it is closed. I am developing a web app for Chrome, but would prefer a solution that is more general. Are any events fired for open and close of the picker?

It looks like *change* events are fired whenever the color picker's color is changed, but I can't see that an event is fired on open.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `on click` to determine when it's opened?

Comment: That might work for open, but what about close? I need both. I'll change my question to include that.

Comment: @OscarLT that does not seem to be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The color picker [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#color-state-%28type=color%29) state that the input events apply. So you could probably do something using the `focus` and `blur` events on the picker and monitor the state of a dedicated variable like the following:

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt4bj582/)

**html**

```
<input id="clr" type="color" />
```

**javascript**

```
(function(){
    var picker = document.getElementById('clr'),
            tog = false;


  picker.addEventListener('focus', function(){
    if(tog === true){
        console.log('open');
    }else{
        console.log('closed');
    }
  });

  picker.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    tog = !tog;
    if(tog === true){
      tog = false;
        console.log('open');
    }else{
        console.log('closed');
    }
  });

}());
```

***Note*** the `focus` event fires twice.

Comment: I think you're printing out the open/closed back to front, and this method gives some iffy results in Chrome where the colour picker is a separate window.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't think there's a reliable way to do this across all browsers. Each browser treats the color input and associated events differently.

Comment: This isn't quite working on chrome (the target browser). The events fire when the input element gains and loses focus, which partially overlaps with the color picker window opening and closing. So, if the color picker stays open, but I click elsewhere, the blur event is fired. This gets me partway there, but not all the way.

Comment: Obviously it's not a reliable way to do it across browsers and even OS's; as I tested it in Chrome in Ubuntu and when the color picker is open it won't let me click elsewhere on the window, that's why I missed it. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome) question's answers have some interesting points on how to proceed since you are writing an extension and probably you could try to close the picker window when it gets out of focus. If all else fails you could implement your own color picker.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any APIs that will help you, best that I could think of is using `click` and `change` events (however `change` won't trigger if user will simply close color picker without making any change):

```
$("input").click(function () { console.log("opened"); });
$("input").change(function () { console.log("closed"); });
```

**Update** in order to handle color picker close without making any choice you could additionally listen for [focusin](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) (after closing color picker it will bring focus back to your input):

```
$("input").click(function () { 
    console.log("opened"); 
  window.colorPickerIsOpened = true; 
});
$("input").change(function () { 
  console.log("closed"); 
  window.colorPickerIsOpened = false; 
});
$("input").focusin(function () { 
    if (window.colorPickerIsOpened) { 
    console.log("closed"); 
    window.colorPickerIsOpened = false; 
  } 
});
```

Comment: I was thinking this as well, however, browsers seem to handle the `change()` event on a color input differently. In Firefox this works, but in Chrome the change event fires any time you move the color selector, not only when the picker is closed.

Comment: @APAD1 maybe you will find easier to use `focusout` instead of `change`, however in this case you might want to add `tabindex="-1"` to your input which will prevent from unwanted triggers if user will play with TAB.

Comment: What @APAD1 said. We don't want to be notified when a value in the color picker changes, but rather when the window is closed.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg then just get rid of `change`, here is working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ronvjhn3/

Comment: For reference, `focusin` listening does not appear to work on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

1. List item
   this is the easiest way i think!

```js
let colour = document.querySelector("input")

let state = false
colour.addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
    if (state) {
        colour.style.display = 'none';
        state = !state;
    } else {
        colour.style.display = 'inline-block';
        state = !state;
    }
})
```

```html
<input type="color">
```