# onfocus and onblur not working for input color element when visibility: hidden; is set

Tags: javascript

Onchange is working. But what is the way to make  onfocus and onblur events to fire when working with input color element when visibility: hidden; is set?

I was seeing the example on internet.
And  I am using it. But it does not work when i have next set in css.

```
#colorDialogID {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

On the end maybe there would be some better solution to register if color dialog was opened and closed without any change?

```
     function getColor2() {  
                 console.log("change");
    }
    document.getElementById("colorDialogID").onchange = getColor2;


    function myFocusFunction() {
        console.log("open"); 
    }

    function myBlurFunction() {
        console.log("close"); 
    }
    document.getElementById("colorDialogID").onfocus = myFocusFunction;
    document.getElementById("colorDialogID").onblur = myBlurFunction;

 var statusName;
 function createStatusF(){  


  document.getElementById("colorDialogID").focus();
  document.getElementById("colorDialogID").value = "#FFCC00"; 
  document.getElementById("colorDialogID").click();  
 }

document.getElementById("newStatuslabelID").onclick = createStatusF;
```

[image: On the botom you may see "change"]

Comment: add the html code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if an <input type="color"> color picker is opened and closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583259/how-to-detect-if-an-input-type-color-color-picker-is-opened-and-closed)

Comment: With FF your code seems to [work as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/cau3o1rn/) ..? Maybe browser dependent? Or do you need an event to fire exactly when a color is picked?

Comment: Work's in chrome too. But it works on the input element (like expected) not the window that opens to pick a color.

Comment: The code and markup as provided do not illustrate any issue as described.  Please update your question with an example that does show the exact actual issue you wish resolved.

Comment: I made one experiment. I have took out all other code except "console.log("change");" And the situation is the same.

Comment: The visibility: hidden; is set and that is the  reason why onblur and onfocus are not firing.

Answer (score 1):

You must have some duplicated id.

I did this demo for you:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="colorDialogID">
  <option value="#df0000">Red
  <option value="#7b93d3">Blue
  <option value="#000000">Black
</select>
  <hr>
  <span>Your selection</span>
  <p id="selectedColor"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function getColor2() {
var x = document.getElementById("colorDialogID").value;
  document.getElementById("selectedColor").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
      console.log("Selected color is:" + x); 
}
document.getElementById("colorDialogID").onchange = getColor2;


function myFocusFunction() {
    console.log("open"); 
}

function myBlurFunction() {
    console.log("close"); 
}
document.getElementById("colorDialogID").onfocus = myFocusFunction;
document.getElementById("colorDialogID").onblur = myBlurFunction;
```

[Working Demo](https://jsbin.com/yujekik/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Presumably "_input color element_" is `<input id="colorDialogID" type="color">` ..?

Comment: Answering to Luiggi about duplication of id. I have only one colorDialogID in my header.

Comment: Also in next case onfocus and on blure are not working: document.getElementById("colorDialogID").style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 0):

You can call function like this 

`document.getElementById("colorDialogID").onfocus = function() {myFocusFunction()};`