# form submit not working in Chrome inconjunction with window

Tags: javascript

```
  objForm.submit();
  window.close();
```

Submit only works when I comment out the the window.close line. I tried adding a 5 second timer in between the 2 lines but that didn't work either.

This works fine in Firefox and IE11

Comment: Scripts are only allowed to close windows that were opened by it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)