# window.close(); Not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.close();
</script>
```

This code doesn't work in Chrome and Fireworks, but it works in IE. What goes wrong? I try it using my friend's Chrome, and it works.

Comment: Do you open this window from JS side?

Comment: You can close a window with JS only if you opened it with JS. If you try to close a window with Chrome console, for example, you get `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.`

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

Comment: http://www.yournewdesigner.com/css-experiments/javascript-window-close-firefox.html maybe this will work

Answer (score 3):

This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console:

> Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.