# Why the original window doesn't close after submit?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```js
function login() {
  var un = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var pw = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (un == "admin" && pw == "admin") {
    window.open("TXL.html", '_blank');
    this.window.close();
    return true;
  }
  else {
    alert("FAIL");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <form action="" class="form center-block" onsubmit="login()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The login-window just refresh after submit.
And I tried `"window.open("TXL.html", '_self');"` and it doesn't work,even can't open the new window.
I also tried window.location.href=""; ,it still doesn't work.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: What is `this.window.close()`? It should probably be `window.close()` or `self.close()`. Still, read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19768082/4477659

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28212/)**.

You've to add return in the `onsubmit` event :

```
<form action="" class="form center-block" onsubmit="return login()">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What you want to achieve? are you tried the wotking fiddle in my answer? is it what you want?

Comment: sry,i want to open a new window then close the login window after submit,not just alert.

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="" class="form center-block" onsubmit="login()">`

Maybe i should use 'onclick' instead of 'onsubmit'?