# Exit Google Sheet via Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using a dialog box OnOpen to validate if a user accepts terms and conditions of use of the Google Sheet.  If the user says no I want the Google sheet to close.  If they say yes then they are welcome to use it.  How can i close a Google sheet programmatically?

Comment: What have you tried already? Please remember that Stack Overflow is not a programming service. We're a community of programmers learning together, to help with questions and specific problems, but we won't do your work for you. Try providing your current attempts and research and highlight specifically what isn't working or what part you're confused on.

Answer (score 0):

In short, Javascript cannot close a window that it didn't open.

[window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the return function to exit.

```
function Exit()
```

{

return;

}