# Automatically close browser/tab without opening it by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i need to close the browser or tab automatically after it open, to do like confirmation page, " Thanks for something, browser gonna close after 2 seconds".

so i try this :

```
<div id="Success" class="Content" onload="winClose()">
...
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function winClose() {
    window.setTimeout("window.close();",2000)
  }
</script>
```

but, the window.close() method can be execute if the browser/tab was open by a script

> Les scripts ne peuvent pas fermer une fenêtre qui n’a pas été ouverte par un script.
>
> Scripts can not close a window that has not been opened by a script.

so, i got a window opening where the user choose between 4 choices, and on click, they fall on a page that tell to the user, that the choice as been register successfully, and Automatically close after 2 seconds. btw im on silex microframework, so if something with controller is possible, tell me.

how can i do this "Automatically close things" without opening the browser/tab by a script ?

Comment: Why do you need to open a whole tab just to show a message?

Comment: this is not a new tab but redirected somewhere else, but i still need to close my tab :/

Comment: As the error says, you can't close a browser window through JavaScript if you didn't create the window through a script to begin with. That's a security/UX feature that's mandated by the HTML5 spec, and it can't be worked around in recent versions of browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: will this help u? window.open('', '_self', '').close();

Comment: There is semicolon after window.close()

Comment: @NicolasChancerel did you find a way to auto-close the new tab?