# How To close the new window automatically when the redirect url API is hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i am using the react js and i am open a new window using this method.

```
var newWindow = window.open(
  this.state.url,
  'myWindow',
  "location=yes,width=600,height=600"
)
```

Using this method a new window is open and a redirection url is open and getting the response in new window i just want to close new window pop up after getting response.
the redirection link is actually a api link in which i am sending the response.

Help me get out of this.
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to instead make the request in the current scope, i.e. with a `fetch` or using `axios`? Or are you trying to close the window automatically after some specified interaction from a user?

Comment: When getting response from api you must be doing something on that data, so at that time you can write the logic for close.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the event loadstop of newwindow and then close it.

Comment: what is the use of load stop

Comment: in new window the api is hitting and url is changed how can i cloase it whilw i am not getting any response in parent window

Comment: Try this, Assuming you have no same-origin problems, that should now work.

var newWindow = window.open(
  "https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/http/",
  'myWindow',
  "location=yes,width=600,height=600"
);newWindow.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event){
    newWindow.close();
});

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach will solve your Issue. At leas if you open the new Window interaktiv.  [Automatically close browser/tab without opening it by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349874/automatically-close-browser-tab-without-opening-it-by-javascript)

Snippet from the other post which should be part of the response (dont know if possible in your case).

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function winClose() {
       window.setTimeout("window.close();",2000)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `newWindow` reference to your window pop up. Now you can listen `onload` method which gets fired once your window is fully loaded with content and `dom` is generated. [Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) here. DO your stuff inside this funciton.

```
newWindow.onload = function() {
  // do your stuff here
  newWindow.close()
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.