# self.close() not working...Is there any work-around for that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have created an HTML page.I want to make that page to close by clicking of a close button the page.I tried using:-

```
window.close()
```

and

```
self.close()
```

method but it is not working on chrome and firefox.I came to know that they wont support these methods anymore.Is there any workaround to do so???please, help....Thanks

Comment: Sure, click the "X" button on the top right corner of the window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

Comment: *Is there any workaround to do so* - no, as `This is a security feature` (according to one answer in the duplicate) I very much doubt there is a workaround or *exploit* to be able to do this - the very fact you want to do this begs the question ... **why?**

Comment: Thank you...I have been working on a project...I got a requirement with this...thats why I asked...