# Using mailto (html) opens a tab with chrome

Tags: html, mailto

I am working on a website to have it be able to use mailto without typing out the email in the script. 
 here is the function

```
<script type= "text/javascript"> 
    function createemail(name,subject) 
      {
      var email = name + '@email.com';
      var mailto_link = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject;
      win = window.open (mailto_link, 'emailWindow');
      //if (window && window.open && !window.closed) window.close()----DOES NOT CLOSE WINDOW };
  </script>
```

I then reference the function with a onclick command

```
   <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">
    <font size="+1"><a onclick = "createemail('TEST','Subject Text')"; style= "cursor:pointer; cursor:hand; color:#0000ee"><u>Sales</u></a></font>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The text is changed to look like a hyperlink but it just references the function

Comment: Why are you using `font`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Function to

```
  <script type= "text/javascript"> 
function createemail(name,subject) 
  {
  var email = name + '@bldgcs.com';
  location.href = 'mailto:' + email +'?subject=' + subject;
  };
```

The location.href seemed to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but if I am correct, you're trying to close the window after the email window has been opened.

*You can't do that.*

Javascript can only close a window that has been opened by it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome) for more information.

*P.S.* Really, why are you using `font`?

Comment: I am revising an old code for a company I am working for and they have font on everything

Comment: Ok, that's a reasonable excuse :P

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want the behavior of that anchor tag to open up your email client (Outlook or whatever) then you have to change the `innerHTML` of the anchor tag with your `mailto_link`. You have to set an `id` for that anchor tag and by using the `document.getElementById('anchorTagId')` you can then later set it.

```
function createemail(name,subject) 
{
var email = name + '@email.com';
var mailto_link = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject;
win = window.open (mailto_link, 'emailWindow');
//if (window && window.open && !window.closed) window.close()----DOES NOT CLOSE WINDOW
var _theEmail = document.getElementById('theEmail');
_theEmail.innerText = mailto_link;
};


<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
          <font size="+1"><a id="theEmail" onclick = "createemail('TEST','Subject Text')"; style= "cursor:pointer; cursor:hand; color:#0000ee"><u>Sales</u></a></font>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```