# How to close current browser tab in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cross-browser

After doing some request I need to clear local storage and close current tab in the browser.
Using `window.close()` or similar doesn't work. It gives me the message

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Comment: window represents the current window, so it is difficult to say why your code do not works as expeted. Can you provide a more coincise snippet ?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini It is duplicate indeed. Being eager to solve this we didn't read the most popular answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19768082/7813852