# How to close browser window after form submission is complete?

Tags: javascript, browser, form-submit

I have old file that has been changed. One of the requests for this file/project modification is when user clicks `OK` to submit the form and close the current browser window. I'm wondering if this can be achieved with plain/vanilla JavaScript? So I have form and button:

```
<form name="test" id="test" action="/save_form.cfm">
   <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: just call `window.close()` on submit

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
window.close();
```

You can type it in your input tag or make a new script tag with that code in it, whenever a button is clicked.

For example

```
<input type="submit" value="OK" onclick="closeWindow();">
```

In addition, you can add return false to 'onclick' to prevent the default actions.

Comment: This will only work if the window was opened with JS, isn't it?

Comment: Yes! You cannot close any window that wasn't opened with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, JavaScript can close the current window, but bare in mind that if the browser has other tabs open, the browser won't close.

```
var closeBtn = document.querySelector("#test input");

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    window.close()
})
```

Comment: So what if submit fails? Or server side validation fails?

Comment: @charlietfl What makes you assume there will be a server side validation?

Comment: Best practices would suggest that. You can't blindly trust user input. Even if there isn't validation there can be network errors, back end issues etc

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onSubmit` event as shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) to call a function and then when its done use `window.close()` to close the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.close();
```

However you can't just close any window. It only works if it's one that you opened yourself. (security feature).

This was already answered in detail [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the window was opened using `window.open()` , have your `save-form.cfm` return a basic html page with script tag to close window when submit and validation is succesfaul

```
<html>

<body>
  <script>window.close()</script>
  <p>Window should close automatically</p>
</body>

</html>
```