# Close current page

Tags: vue.js

I want to close my current browser tab in Chrome in my Vue.js code.

I have tried many things like

```
close()

window.close()

window.open('','_self').close()
```

None of these close my current page/ tab

Comment: I don't think this is possible in most cases. [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) for `window.close()` says "This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open() method."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: I saw this post before posting, thinking that there might be a solution now