# How to close the Chrome browser automatically after a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cron

I wrote a Web Extension which starts surfing specified websites automatically after the Chrome browser is opened.

As far as i know Javascript doesn't allow closing the Chrome browser easily.

**(window.open => window.close didn't work for me.)**

My cronjob will start/open Chrome at certain times and allow the Web Extension to work.

I guess that after some time too many Chrome browsers will be open, so i would like to close them.

Either after the website surfing is complete (there is a certain condition) or after like 30 minutes.

**Are there any options?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: Extension can quit the browser by enumerating all windows and closing them, see chrome.windows API. However a better solution might be for you to use Puppeteer to automate whatever you do instead of an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing every tab would close the window in Google Chrome.

```
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function() { });
    });

});
```