# How to close the router opened in new tab on logout in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi i have used anchor tag for opening the routerLink in new tab. Now if i click on logout, the routerLink in the new tab remains same, if there is any API hit then the routerLink redrirects to login page. But i want all the tabs to close as soon i logout, as the other router pages doesnt have header in the screen.

**Header.component.ts:**

```
public logout() {
    this.authservice.logOutSuccess(true);
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
    this.cookieService.delete(TPIConstants.AUTH_TOKEN);
  }
```

Here in the header component, if i click on logout i am clearing the cookie, so the screen redirects to login page.

But in the landing page, i have add new button, when i click on that it opens the router in the new tab,

**Landing.html:**

```
 <a class="btn btn-light" target="_blank" [routerLink]="['/profile']"> Add New</a>
```

Profile Screen opens in new Tab now.

So, i have used a common service called auth.service in which i have used subject

**auth.service.ts:**

```
 public  detectLogOutSubject = new Subject<any>();
  logOutConfirmed$ = this.detectLogOutSubject.asObservable();

 logOutSuccess(value) {
    this.detectLogOutSubject.next(value);
  }
```

so when i click on logout, it comes to the authservice and triggers this event, and in profile page i have written like this in the constructor method

**profile.component.ts: and app.component.ts**

```
constructor(){
    this.subscription = this.authService.logOutConfirmed$.subscribe(
      res => {
        alert(res)
    });
   }
```

Profile.html:

```
<div>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="window.close();" title="Close Window">
                    <i class="fas fa-times fa-1x"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
```

In profile html, i have the above div section, if that click triggered also, it will close the tab, but i am not able to get the event from logout function to profile screen/app.component also, i am struck, no where getting how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

Because you aren't using a window.open() to open the new tab, your Javascript will not have permission to close the tab. If closing the tab is important, then you need to use window.open() to open the tab and then you can use window.close() to close it when you are ready.

More discussion about the security and permissions can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome/19768082#19768082).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but when i used window.open i faced problem in deployment, so i changed to routerLink. and here the event is not detecting, as the screen is opening in new tab

Comment: is there any better approach to handle this?