# System.exit() equivalent in angular?

Tags: angular, exit

Is there an Angular2+ equivalent to java's system.exit()?
I am wanting to create a button on my app that stops running the code, but can't find something similar.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops running the code"? This is an application hosted on a server somewhere, not something running on your laptop.

Comment: this seems like a strange request for a webapp.  what specific behavior do you want to stop when the user clicks the button?  what does the user see after they click the button?

Comment: And more importantly, what do _other users_ see after your first user clicks the button?

Comment: What I mean by "stops running the code" is quitting the app and closing the browser. For example, if a user is finished using the app, the browser will close. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking in terms of closing your Angular program so here it will be like closing your tab

System.exit equivalent is [window.close or just close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close#:%7E:text=The%20Window.,a%20script%20using%20the%20Window.&text=content%E2%80%8BWindow%20.) but we have issues with them

[we can only close tabs which we have opened programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)