# Tab kill function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, exit

I'm the one who started JavaScript yesterday.
I made code like this.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            alert('Hello world \nNice to meet you \n');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, after the code was finished, it was inconvenient to only leave blank pages.
Is there a function in JavaScript that kills the running browser tab?

I use Windows as the operating system and Chrome as the browser.

========
'Window.close();' in the last line of code I added it, but nothing happened.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            alert('Hello world \nNice to meet you \n');
            window.close();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sure `window.close();`

Comment: On `window.close()`, the window should close after the user clicks the alert button.

Answer (score 0):

window.close() will close the current tab.

Refer this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome) to get an idea why window.close() doesn't work for you.
And I also suggest you to clear the cache and sessions and try again.