# How to implement a secure implementation of chrome.tabs.remove()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, browser-extension

### Use case

- Existing web page / URL is opened from a 3rd party app. Upon completion of the work on the web page, it is expected to close
  itself.
- Javascript does not allow it using window.close() or alike, ref.
  [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Browser limitation (Firefox/Chrome) is well documented and explored over the past years. For the given use case, per my understanding closing of a browser tab can only be achieved from a background script, calling [chrome.tabs.remove](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-remove)() API.

### Browser extension

The approach that seemed logical to me is using the following artifacts.

**content.js**

```
document.addEventListener("myCloseTabEvent", function(e){
  console.log("[content] originating domain: " + this.domain);

  // Prepare message for background script
  var myMsgContent = {
    type: "myAction",
    value: "CloseBrowserTab"}

  browser.runtime.sendMessage(myMsgContent);
}, false);
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(msgData, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msgData.type == "myAction" && msgData.value == "CloseBrowserTab") {
      chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);
    } else {
      console.log("[background] No action because !(myAction && CloseBrowserTab)");
    }
 });
```

**Changes to web page to raise the new event**

```
function mySendEvent() {
  const myEvent = new Event("myCloseTabEvent"); // OR CustomEvent()

  // Dispatch the event
  document.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
}
```

In summary, the following happens:

1. The web page loads
2. Content script adds the event listener for a custom event `myCloseTabEvent`
3. Background script adds an onMessage listener using chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()
4. Once all work is done on the page, existing Javascript code dispatches the custom event by calling `mySendEvent()`.
5. Content script runs its listener `function(e)`, sending a message to the background script.
6. Background script onMessage listener `function(msgData, sender, sendResponse)` uses the sender object to determine the tabId, and closes the browser tab using `chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);`

### Questions

1. In concept, is this approach the best option we have to achieve the goal of closing the browser tab? Would there be any better ways of achieving the same?
2. A background script is require to be able to close the tab (correct me if I'm wrong here). Therefore the browser extension cannot be restricted to be active only on a specific set of domains using [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/) -> `matches`. What best practices exists to restrict the functionality of the browser extension like this to specific domains? (domain names are known to the users of the extension, but not while packaging the artifacts). This is especially is of interest, to prevent other (malicious) web pages from closing them selves by sending the same message to the background script of the extension.