# Can no longer close current window with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, window

Until recently this worked in all browsers to close the current window:

`window.open('','_self').close();`

That no longer seems to be the case in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. I can fix it in Firefox by opening about:config and setting dom.allow_scripts﻿_to_close_windows to true. Does anyone know of a remedy for the others?

Comment: That code still works in Chrome for me.  Have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close ?

Comment: If my understanding is correct the window will be closed if it was opened with window.open function. Else, it may not.

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: I just tried doing this by hand in the console in Chrome, and I got the error `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: @PaulRooney The answers there say that `close()` can only be called by the same script that called `open()`. That's what this code does. How does that question help?