# window.close fails when clicking links within opened window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a new window with window.open().  If I do NOTHING else on this page, and click the "close window" link, the window closes.  This works perfectly; however, if I navigate between pages(all under the same domain) window.close() no longer works.

Is there a way to fix this?

### Here is how I am opening pages in this example...

```
<a href="###" target="_blank">
```

### Here is my close link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.close()">close</a>
```

### I use 2 methods of changing pages within the opened windows.

`<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">` AND STANDARD `<a href="####">` tag

Do I need to navigate links within this window a certain way to still maintain my `window.close()` ability?

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome - You should use  `window.open()` to open the window because `window.close()` can only be used on windows that were opened with `window.open` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: window.close is working as long as I don't navigate between links on the window.  Once I navigate between pages, window.close stops working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should favour using `window.open()` to open a new window if you want to close it using `window.close()`. E.g.

```
<script>
  function newWindow() {
    window.open('foo.html', 'myWindow'); 
    return false;
  }
</script>
  
<a href="foo.html" onclick="return newWindow()">link</a>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close):

> The Window.close() method closes the current window, or the window on which it was called. This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script`.

I understand the behaviour you're describing where you can close the window as long as you don't navigate. I can replicate this in Google Chrome.

I believe this is because (from [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html#dom-window-close)):

> A browsing context is script-closable if it is an auxiliary browsing context that was created by a script (as opposed to by an action of the user), **or if it is a top-level browsing context whose session history contains only one `Document`**.

Your new window is considered a "top-level browsing context", not an "auxilliary browsing context". Up until the point that you navigate, the history contains one document, so can be closed using `window.close()`. As soon as you navigate, the history has more than one document so it's not valid to close the window.

---

You should also have a read about `window.opener` and the security risks it poses.

`window.opener` provides a reference to the `window` object that opened the current window.

Recent advice is to use `rel="noopener"` on all links that open in new windows. Again, this is because setting `window.opener` without knowing what you're doing poses a security risk. Have a read about it here:

**[Links to cross-origin destinations are unsafe](https://web.dev/external-anchors-use-rel-noopener/)**

Browsers are now starting to treat all `target="_blank"` links as if `rel="noopener"` had been set, even if you as a developer don't set it. You can see that [this is now in most major browsers](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6140064063029248).

Therefore, you *could* use `<a href="#" target="_blank" rel="opener">link</a>` (explicitly setting `window.opener`) and I think you'd get the behaviour you want. However, this might not be reliable across browsers, and also has security implications as described in the web.dev article.

Comment: Thank you!  This is for an internal system for same domain urls so I believe that adding `rel="opener"` should be a safe solution.