# The javascript window.close() does not work

Tags: javascript

I have page that open a new window. On this window there is close button. The close button works fine.

```
<input type="button" onClick="javascript:window.close()" value="Close Window" class="uportal-button" style="position: absolute; right: 3px; top: 5px; z-index: 1;">
```

On this page, I have a html form and Save button. If you save the page and then click "close". The close button does not work.

Any suggestions on how to fix this. I tried suggestions from [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome) article but did not work

Comment: ["This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) Is this the case?

Comment: When you submit the form does it reload a new page and is it a page you control the code in?

Comment: it looks like when I save the page, its not the page that opened the window. Is there a way I can write a function to loop through all the parent/child window and close them.

Comment: Tried the following also as workaround but getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null"<script type="text/javascript">
 function quitBox(cmd) 
{      
    if (cmd=='quit')    
    {   
       window.opener.postMessage(window.location, '*');
       window.open(window.location, '_self').close();    
    }     
    return false;   
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="return quitBox('quit');" value="Close Window" class="uportal-button" >

Comment: I have an app that opens a window to do oauth through another service. When other service redirects back to my site I just call window.close() in  script tag. I also keep checking in my app that opened the window for `newWindow.closed` so I know when it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The `Window.close()` method closes the current window, or the window on which it was called.

This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the `Window.open()` method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) for more details.

Comment: We don't know if this answers the question which is why I asked the in the comment section if this was the case. At the moment this is just supposition.

Comment: OK I see. I didn't understand well. Thank