# How to I use inspect element to close the window without it having to open it too?

Tags: javascript, window.closed

Each time I try to use `window.close();` I just get the error `Scripts may only close the windows that were opened by them`, is there any way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it’s not.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close):

> This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the `Window.open()` method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

See also [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19768082/17698708/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome/19768082#19768082