# Close Window opened manually in script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I am trying to close the current tab when the user clicks on the 'CloseWindow' Button. Whatever I try

```
VM303:1 Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.
```

statement is displayed. I tried all the workarounds using self, `window.opener.close()` etc.
Has anyone done and it's working please share and help. I am using React framework. I am trying this in a jsx file.

Comment: [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: In Javascript to close a window you just need to do window.close()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)