# Visit Multiple Links in the Same New Window

Tags: javascript, html

I want to visit multiple links in the same new window.

Lets say I open `google.com` in a new window after that I open `yahoo.com` but this has to open in the same window where `google.com` was opened by re-loading the same `google.com` window.

I have this website as a reference `http://doubleadvertise.com` just trying to achieve something similar to this website.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">google</a><br>
<a href="https://www.bing.com/" target="_blank">bing</a><br>
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com/" target="_blank">yahoo</a>
```

How to achieve this thanks

Comment: You can't do this in just HTML, but if you use `window.open()` in JavaScript it returns a window handle you can use, but keep in mind this will only work if the website does not have the `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` set to `same-origin-allow-popups` as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72993615/10601203).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do this using some basic JavaScript. You can use the [`Window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) method to open a new window. This method also returns a handle to the opened window so you can perform actions such as [setting `Window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) which will redirect the tab to a different page. You can still use the `_blank` target like you're doing in your HTML.

```
let newWindow = null;

function openLink(link){
  if(newWindow === null){
    newWindow = window.open(link, '_blank');
  }
  else{
    newWindow.location.href = link;
  }
}

openLink('https://google.com/');
setTimeout(() => openLink('https://yahoo.com/'), 2000); // Delay it 2 seconds so previous link as time to open
setTimeout(() => openLink('https://bing.com/'), 4000); // Delay it 4 seconds so previous link as time to open
```

<sub>I can't include this code as a runnable snippet because popups are blocked, so [here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Appeaze/r298qy61/). Note you will need to enable popups.</sub>

Keep in mind that this will not work for websites that have the `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` header set to `same-origin-allow-popups` (Google Translate for example) as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72993615/10601203). There is no workaround, you will just have to avoid these websites.