# why first time window.close does not work

Tags: javascript, angular

What i see in docs that if you open the tab manually using `window.open` then you have option to close it.

```
 openNewWindow() {
    const newWindow = window.open('https://www.google.com/', 'hello');
    setTimeout(() => {
      newWindow?.close();
    }, 100);
  }
```

Playground Link: [Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g3wumv?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Have you tried it with a longer timeout? 100 milliseconds might be to short for the window to open, thus leading to `newWindow` being null and not calling the `close` function.

Comment: 100ms could be too short. either that new window is not ready yet to be closed again, and/or there is some security mechanism in place. popups are always a bad idea, and closing a popup within 100ms sounds especially bad

Comment: @Geshode `newWindow` will definitely not be null. the reference will exist instantly. but it may not be closable

Comment: @MarianTheisen I tried with longer duration too but still same it does not close

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the internet speed. If opening a new window takes more than 100ms. The newWindow object is not yet initialized and newWindow?.close() will not be executed.

Comment: I tried with longer duration as well but the result is same

Comment: I tried several times and got the right result every time. Read the link below, maybe you will come to a conclusion
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19768082/9737587

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work with other URLs.

Try with `example.org` or `developer.mozilla.org`.

Maybe `www.google.com` has a feature that prevents the window from being closed.